# How to Create a Custom-shaped Fishnet Grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-grid, hexagonal-grid

I am looking to automate the create of a fishnet grid over a large area (about the size of Rhode Island) for a mapping study. I want to use hexagonal grid cells, but the kicker is I need each of these hexagonal grids again broken down into their 6 hexants. The center convergent vertex will be a setup location with mapping done out to the extent of each hexant. Sort of like flying the petals from the pistil of a flower.

[image]

I don't see custom grid shapes in QGIS. I'm wondering how I can create this grid layout.

My first thought was to lay down hex grids and then do a series of layer copying with systematic offsets and a final merge to get what I need. Or to convert grids to polylines, copy those lines with the bearings I want, and repaste/offset those. But there's got to be other tools or a simpler process out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here is my suggestion, if I understood you correctly, proceed as follows,

i.e. it is a technique that can be automated:

Input data are hexagons fig. 1

[image]

1. Vector>Processing geometry>Point extract;
2. Data Analysis>Toolbar>General Vector>Erase the same geometry - **this is important!**
3. Create centroids on the hexagon layer, copy them and paste them into the "Cleared Vertices" layer;
4. Run Vector>Processing geometry>Triangulation Delaunay on the updated merged point layer "Clear Vertices"....
5. Run Vector>Geo-processing>Crossing (results layer 4 and hexagon)

And you should get what you ask...fig. 2

[image]

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't seem to find "Crossing". Is it called something else? And by "Erase the same geometry", you're referring to "delete duplicate geometries", correct?

Comment: these are translation problems! 1) Maybe Intersection...2) "delete duplicate geometries" - yes, that's right...

Comment: Great thanks. Also I ran my delaunay triangulation on the de-duped vertices + centroids point layer, but this is the resulting triangles. It seems off. https://imgur.com/a/aw4bVXl.

Comment: Hmmm. Yep that is what I used. Toolbox->Vector General->Delete Duplicate Geometries. Then pasted the centroids into that points layer. Then ran Delaunay. The results are the imgur screenshot. Reran, same results.

Comment: Then pasted the centroids into that points layer. After this action you saved the changes? Then ran Delaunay.

Comment: That is correct. Here is a link to my layers. https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/895736/shapefiles.zip

Comment: So far, I have found out that the original hexagon file is wrong, so I specify you created it with the geo tool "Create vector objects">"Create a grid">"Hexagons" or another tool?

Comment: Try to use in your original polygons the proposed tool to create hexagons, because if the geometry is correct, geoinstruments work correctly, if the geodata is wrong, then geoinstruments simply do not work...

Comment: Yes I used Vector>Research Tools>Create a Grid>Hexagons. I also found upon further inspection that there are some erroneous vertices generated and remaining even after removing duplicate geometry. Once I manually deleted those bad vertices of the process worked. Now to figure out why those erroneous extraneous vertices :-/  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, you also need to check your source data for which you created the hexagons, whether they are correct...